# Preventing sent email from getting labeled as spam

Tags: domain-name-system, email, vps, spam

I have recently started renting an Ubuntu VPS from OVH.
I have configured it as an *iRedMail* instance, planning on using it to send and receive personal emails.
This all went smoothly, and the mail is indeed sent and received properly.

My problem is that a few popular email providers like gmail and outlook mark the (personal / non-commercial) email sent from this domain as spam.
Therefore, I went through the classic checklist for this kind of problems :

- IP address isn't blacklisted on any spam list at all
- All DNS records are setup correctly, including DKIM, SPF and DMARC
- The content of the emails doesn't look like spam (all classic personal messages)

I ran through spam tests, here are the results from [mail-tester](http://www.mail-tester.com/web-61r27C) (last was 10/10, I did another one not to use my personal email) and [isnotspam](http://www.isnotspam.com/newlatestreport.php?email=ins-ny0ugh42%40isnotspam.com). Nothing out of the ordinary, everything seems perfect except "*Bayes spam probability is 99 to 100%*", could this cause the mails being put into spam ? I have literally no idea why this probability is so high, my mail server isn't an open relay, I don't have any proxy server open, and my VPS provider blocks SMTP port if it detects outgoing spam.

Does anyone have an idea of what might cause my problem ?

Thanks !

PS : There are obviously other posts like mine, but I've already checked them and none of them provide an answer to my case.

Answer (score 1):

The BAYES_99 score is supposedly based on a user's past history. You say you're on a VPS, so I'm not sure if that history would be comprised of domain name or IP address. Do you have access to a different mail server? If so, perhaps try sending the exact same email from a different server (different domain, different IP) and see if you get the same result?

If that doesn't get the same BAYES_99 score on the receiving end, then you've narrowed it down.

Keep in mind, with BAYES_99, you don't necessarily have to have a CURRENT blacklist in effect, but your IP might have been used heavily in the past as a source of spam.